# MVC and Jquery Datables implementing paging withing the stored procedure?

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, model-view-controller, datatables

I have a .NET MVC application that uses Jquery Datatables, is it possible to have both paging and filtering implemented within a stored procedure. Datables needs the result total back, just wondering how that would get tied in with EF/Proc and back to the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, although DataTables is much less useful in this case. This blog posts shows you how: http://www.woodcp.com/2012/02/server-side-paging-with-petapoco-and-datatables/

Full documentation is here: http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side
(Note that at the time of writing the documentation hasn't been updated and is for the older version of DataTables. Follow the upgrade guides if you are using a later version).

For performance reason I would say that you almost certainly *do* want to page on the server-side unless you can guarantee that you will always have a low number of records to display (in which case I would usually question why you would bother with paging in the first place).